# Theoretical speedup not achieved - kernel separability

Tags: performance, matlab, convolution

I am seeing how to improve the time it takes for convolution using kernel separability. Below is a piece of code demonstrating this:

```
test = randn(3000);
kx = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];
ky = kx';
kernel = ky*kx;

tic; b = conv2(test,kernel,'same'); toc;

tic; bx=conv2(test,kx, 'same'); by=conv2(bx,ky, 'same'); toc;
```

Running the above code yields these results:

Elapsed time is 0.564579 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.333260 seconds.

As can be seen, this is not the theoretical speedup that I am expecting, which is supposed to be 81/18 = 4.5.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: It could be a variety of things.  It also may be due to function overhead where you're calling the function twice.  Bear in mind that those are **theoretical speedups**.  Practically is another story.  Also, is that code being run in a function or in the command prompt?  There is additional timing overhead if you run it in the command prompt.

Comment: Note also that those times are very large for such a small amount of processing, so the times are probably being swamped by operations other than the convolution itself. Try applying the kernel to a decent sized 2D data set, e.g. 1024x1024.

Comment: To compare, when I ran both lines of code, I got `0.072947` and `0.067429` seconds respectively.  I ran the test probably 10 different times and my times are hovering around those.  I put this into a function script and ran it.... so I don't see any appreciable difference.  Perhaps `conv2` takes separability into account when providing a 2D kernel and splits it up into 2 1D kernels for you if it can.

Comment: I'm running it from the workspace in Matlab... I will try running it on a smaller dataset

Comment: Try also `tic; by=conv2(kx, ky, test, 'same'); toc`

Comment: @user1816546 - Place your code in a function script and run it.  Doing it directly in the command prompt has additional overhead.

Comment: @LuisMendo the time actually increased which is expected...

Comment: @rayryeng so the reason is the additional overhead? I just ran it from a function and the times are 

Elapsed time is 0.690701 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.473887 seconds.

still far from the speedup im expecting. Does it have to do with how Matlab allocates its resources?

Comment: @user1816546 - It could be a variety of different things.  It may be that there are background processes that are taking priority over your CPU, or it could be the function overhead as we talked about, or it may be the actual data itself.  To be consistent, try generating the same random sequence before each test.  Set the random seed generator through `rng` to be some number.  That way, you know you'll be using the same data each time for each test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your kernel is not big enough to really see any gains. The improvement should become more apparent as you make the kernel larger:

```
test = randn(3000);
kx = 1:100;
ky = kx';
kernel = ky*kx;

tic; b = conv2(test,kernel,'same'); toc;
tic; bx=conv2(test,kx, 'same'); by=conv2(bx,ky, 'same'); toc;
```

When I run it with this 100x100 kernel size, I see:

```
Elapsed time is 6.961222 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.252186 seconds.
```

With a 200x200 kernel I get:

```
Elapsed time is 28.894932 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.639125 seconds.
```

When we double the kernel size, the 2D kernel time increases by a factor of ~4.15, and the 1D time increases by a factor of ~2.5. Not far off from the theoretical increase of 4x and 2x respectively.

Answer (score 1):

This is not answering your question (kmac's answer covers that), but if you're looking for a performance improvement, then you may be better off getting away from the `conv` function.  Doing an FFT/IFFT to achieve the same result is much faster in Matlab.  There are several tradeoffs in going from a traditional convolution to the Fourier approach, but it might be helpful in your application.  There are some great thoughts on the topic here:
http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2009/11/03/the-conv-function-and-implementation-tradeoffs/